# scaling two images to the same or converting an image inside drawable to bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, byte, android-imageview

```
mmr.setDataSource(files[i].getPath());
rawArt = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();//rawart is of type byte
if ( rawArt != null) 
{   
    bitmap2=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawArt, 0, rawArt.length, bfo);
    bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, 150, 150, true);
    detail.setIcon(bitmap2);//seticon here is of bitmap type
}
else {
    detail.setIcon(R.drawable.ab);//seticon here is of bitmap type
}
```

Detail is an object of songdetails.
In the songdetails,
I have two functions "setIcon" with different data types
one is an int and the other is of bitmap.

What i am doing is if there is an album art attached with a song ,i am displaying it.(after scaling it to 150X150)

If not i am displaying a default  image of type int (stored in drawable-xxhdpi dimensions 270X270)

I used it on an htc phone and the image with dimns. 150X150 is bigger than of dimns. 270X270(maybe because this image is being rescaled and adjusted according to the screen size and etc) .but i don't want this.....i want them to be of the same size (of 150x150).

What i have thought is i can take this image (R.drawable.ab  type int) convert it  into bitmap  and then rescale it by using this function

```
bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, 150, 150, true);
```

But i don't know how to do it .....thanx in advance..any other solution will aslo be appreciated.

Comment: i came to know how to do it

 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ab);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i came to know how to do it

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ab);